# How to update Ubuntu when its installed parallel to Windows 7 on one machine

Tags: updates, windows-7

Current Ubuntu version is 12.04 and want to update it to 14.04, but do not want to disturb Windows 7 which is parallel installed on same machine.
Please help with steps, thanks.

Comment: The update process is same, whether windows is installed or not... Update using downloaded  iso to avoid issues.. Anyway, if it's not urgent I would recommend you to wait until 21st and update directly to 16.04

Comment: @mayankbudhwani are you sure that it's possible to upgrade 12.04 to 16.04 while skipping 14.04?

Comment: Of course.. You can go to 16.04 directly using disc image from ubuntu website.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the normal update process as described [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04).

Windows will *not* be disturbed by Ubuntu upgrades. Only Windows upgrades disturb Ubuntu.